# Python: how to print argparse in alphabetical order

Tags: python, argparse

I am looking for a canonical way to print the returned arguments of `argparse` in alphabetical order:

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Some program', add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('--bb', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--aa', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args) # Output: Namespace(bb=..., aa=...), but I want aa appears before bb
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would that be any different to sorting literally any other collection in python?

Comment: Why would the order matter?

Comment: @kindall Because I have around a hundred of arguments and it's difficult to locate a specific one of them in the logs without sorting.

Comment: The order is going to be determined by the ordering in which the command-line arguments are processed, not (for example) by the order in which you defined the options. Also note that the `Namespace` object is created *before* the arguments are parsed, being updated by each argument's `Action`, rather than receiving a single `dict` after parsing is complete. You're going to have to explicitly sort the values yourself after `parse_args` completes, so you might as well just do something `args = Namespace(**sorted(args.__dict__))`.

Comment: There's also nothing special about `Namespace`. The only expectation by the parser is that whatever you have has the ability to have attributes attached to it. You can define your own argument holder that keeps things sorted and pass an instance to `parse_args`, for example `args = p.parse_args(namespace=MySortedCollection())`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks a lot! Converting to a dictionary was necessary: `sorted_args = argparse.Namespace(**dict(sorted(args.__dict__.items())))`. Otherwise I got the following error: `TypeError: argparse.Namespace() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list`. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Is the a reason they are not (cannot be) *defined* in alphabetical order?  The maintainer would likely be grateful.  (From personal experience …)

Comment: @S3DEV, see my answer for the patch that changed it from sorted to the current, as-added,  order.  A core developer, R. Hettinger, made this change.

Comment: @hpaulj - Ah, the legend himself.  :-)  Thanks, will certainly have a read through your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argparse.Namespace` is a subclass of `_AttributeHolder`.  It's its `__repr__` method that produces the display.

```
class _AttributeHolder(object):
    """Abstract base class that provides __repr__.

    The __repr__ method returns a string in the format::
        ClassName(attr=name, attr=name, ...)
    The attributes are determined either by a class-level attribute,
    '_kwarg_names', or by inspecting the instance __dict__.
    """

    def __repr__(self):
        type_name = type(self).__name__
        arg_strings = []
        star_args = {}
        for arg in self._get_args():
            arg_strings.append(repr(arg))
        for name, value in self._get_kwargs():
            if name.isidentifier():
                arg_strings.append('%s=%r' % (name, value))
            else:
                star_args[name] = value
        if star_args:
            arg_strings.append('**%s' % repr(star_args))
        return '%s(%s)' % (type_name, ', '.join(arg_strings))
    def _get_kwargs(self):
        return list(self.__dict__.items())
```

So with your parser:

```
In [198]: args = parser.parse_args([])
In [199]: args
Out[199]: Namespace(bb=None, aa=None)
In [200]: args.__dict__
Out[200]: {'bb': None, 'aa': None}
```

The display order is just that of the objects `__dict__`.  Attributes with their default values are placed in the new Namespace at the beginning of parsing, with the order determined by order of the `add_argument` commands.

```
In [206]: parser.parse_args(['--bb=xxx'], namespace=ns)
Out[206]: Namespace(aa='foo', bb='xxx')
```

One way of changing this order is to create a namespace object before hand, and pass that to the parser.  The parser won't add any defaults that are already defined.  User input can change values, but won't change the order:

```
In [207]: ns = argparse.Namespace(aa='foo', bb='bar')
In [208]: parser.parse_args([], namespace=ns)
Out[208]: Namespace(aa='foo', bb='bar')
In [209]: parser.parse_args(['--bb=xxx'], namespace=ns)
Out[209]: Namespace(aa='foo', bb='xxx')
```

You could also define a custom `Namespace` class that has its own display order, or tweak the `__repr__` of the existing one.

I vaguely recall that originally the attributes were sorted, and that some relatively recent patch changed that.  I'd have to check the bug/issues to see if that's the case.

As noted in the comments, you can get the namespace in dict form

```
In [213]: vars(parser.parse_args([]))
Out[213]: {'bb': None, 'aa': None}
```

and as you comment:

```
In [218]: argparse.Namespace(**dict(sorted(args.__dict__.items())))
Out[218]: Namespace(aa=None, bb=None)
```

Originally `dict` order was indeterminant, or at least somewhat based on the hashing.  Not too long ago that was changed so that `dict` order is determined by assignment order.

### edit

In May 2020 a patch removed the sorting, https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/9681953c99b686cf23d1c476a2b26d2ddbec7694

```
def _get_kwargs(self):
-    return sorted(self.__dict__.items())
+    return list(self.__dict__.items())
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83239

> Currently, Namespace() objects sort the attributes in the **repr**. This is annoying because argument order matters and because everywhere else in the module we preserve order (i.e. users see help in the order that arguments are added).

> Note, the docs do not promise that Namespace is displayed with a sort. This is likely just an artifact of older dictionaries having arbitrary or randomised ordering.